# Regression model error: Input 0 of layer "hidden1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 11

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0

I created a simple regression model for training on a csv data. I have successfully done the training and evaluation as well, but when I am trying to pass a single row for predicting its output, I am getting a input shape error.

I have tried it in google collab.

Here is the code below.

```
# load libraries and csv
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

insurance_data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/insurance.csv")

insurance_data.head()

# import the Classes. 
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# set up Normalization and One Hot encoding for columns. 
CT = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["age", "bmi", "children"]), #normalize all these columns only. 
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["sex", "smoker", "region"])
)


# make X and Y. 
X1 = insurance_data.drop("charges", axis=1)
Y1 = insurance_data["charges"]


# make Train and Test data. 
X1_train, X1_test, Y1_train, Y1_test = train_test_split(X1, Y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Fit column transformer to our Training data only. 
CT.fit(X1_train)

# transform training and test data with Normalization
X1_train_normalized = CT.transform(X1_train)
X1_test_normalized = CT.transform(X1_test)


X1_train.shape, X1_train_normalized.shape


# make the model, 
tf.random.set_seed(43)

insurance_v3 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(11)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=None, name="hidden1"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=None, name="hidden2"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name="out1")
], name="insurance_model_v3")

insurance_v3.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mae, 
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["mae"]
)

insurance_v3.fit(X1_train_normalized, Y1_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
insurance_v3.evaluate(X1_test_normalized, Y1_test)

# test custom output. 

t = X1_train_normalized[2]
t = tf.convert_to_tensor(t, tf.float64)
t = tf.expand_dims(t, 1)
t
insurance_v3.predict(t)
```

I have taken a row from the Normalized X training (which I am not supposed to do) just to see whether it accepts it and returns a Y value. But it is not working at all.

Can you tell me how to do it properly so than I can take values from a website form, turn it into a tensor and then pass it to the model and then the model returns a value?
as I am supposed to use this model in a django app.

I tried converting the row into a tensor but everytime it is giving me one or the other error. At first, I am getting an ndim error of required dimension of 2, but then sometimes I get an error of unrank tensor.

Comment: I have normalized the CSV data before training, so when I am passing a row to the model from the user, does that has to be normalized as well? Or I just need to make sure that the row has the same number of columns as the one-hot-encoded CSV data has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reshape input (t) before feeding it to the network, and for reshaping tensors you must enable behavior. try this, it runs successfully:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
t = t.reshape(1, -1)
insurance_v3.predict(t)
```

Comment: Hi, so much thank you for this. Will this technique work if I manually create a row(contains user entered info), turn it into a tensor, apply this reshape and then pass it to the insurance_v3 model?

Comment: In every situation, you must check your input shape and its second dimension must be the same size as the second dimension in the train set shape. If you got your answer please check it as "Answered".

Comment: Hi, can you explain to me what parameters you passed to the reshape since I am not able to understand even looking at the documentation either? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's very simple actually, "reshape" gets the dimensions that you desire for the input and reshapes it to have desired dimensions. for example, if you have an array "s" with shapes (1, 12) you could use s.reshape(3, 4) to turn it into a 2-dimensional array with 3 rows and 4 columns. you can also use s.reshape(3, -1), and this way you said to Python you need to reshape your array to have 3 rows and Python itself does the calculation that in every row how many elements it must put.

Comment: In your problem, you need to have every input in the shape (1, 11) but your tensor is in the shape (11, 1), so I used reshape(1, -1) to flatten every input.

Comment: Thank you Thank you . I understood very clearly. I am following a course and recently found out, Tensorflow has expand_dims() to take care of this issue but some versions don't do this automatically(above 2.7 mainly).